# Getting a white screen when running npm start for my React webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router

When I run npm start my webpage is blank and shows no errors however there is a warning on the console: *"index.js:1 Warning: The tag  is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter."*

I have googled this error and looked for hours online at how to solve this white screen issue, and none of the solutions have solved my issue. I am using Firebase also and have setup the authentication etc.. and so I want to be able to see it works

I was also following this ROBIN WIERUCH's step by step tutorial to set the site up so surprised I am having this white page issue: https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial

here is a screenshot of the blank page and console log: https://i.stack.imgur.com/76ZZU.png

Below is relevant code:

src/components/App/index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router as Router, Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import { HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import * as ROUTES from '../../constants/routes';
import { withAuthentication } from '../Session';

import Navigation from '../Navigation';
import LandingPage from '../Landing';
import SignUpPage from '../SignUp';
import SignInPage from '../SignIn';
import PasswordForgetPage from '../PasswordForget';
import HomePage from '../Home';
import AccountPage from '../Account';
import AdminPage from '../Admin';
import { AuthUserContext } from '../Session';
 

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Navigation />

      <hr />
      <Route exact path={ROUTES.LANDING} component={LandingPage} />
      <Route path={ROUTES.SIGN_UP} component={SignUpPage} />
      <Route path={ROUTES.SIGN_IN} component={SignInPage} />
      <Route path={ROUTES.PASSWORD_FORGET} component={PasswordForgetPage} />
      <Route path={ROUTES.HOME} component={HomePage} />
      <Route path={ROUTES.ACCOUNT} component={AccountPage} />
      <Route path={ROUTES.ADMIN} component={AdminPage} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);

    


export default withAuthentication(App);
```

My index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import Firebase, { FirebaseContext } from './components/Firebase';

ReactDOM.render(
  <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}>
    <App />
  </FirebaseContext.Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);


reportWebVitals();
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "job-tracler",
  "homepage":".",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.0",
    "firebase": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

If there are any other files/code that are needed please comment below and I will edit and include them!

edit:
src/components/Firebase/context.js:

```
import React from 'react';
 
const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null);

export const WithFirebase = Component => props => (
    <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
        {firebase => <component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}
    </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
);
 

export default FirebaseContext;
```

src/components/Firebase/index.js:

```
import FirebaseContext, { WithFirebase } from './context';
import Firebase from './firebase';
 
export default Firebase;
 
export { FirebaseContext, WithFirebase };
```

src/components/Firebase/firebase.js

```
  import app from 'firebase/app';
  import 'firebase/auth';

  var firebaseConfig = {//configures firebase for this app
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBEXzmTWMIXRvBXy4h57iaI_6_3hNoN2hk",
    authDomain: "job-tracker-da126.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://job-tracker-da126.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "job-tracker-da126",
    storageBucket: "job-tracker-da126.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "846731062992",
    appId: "1:846731062992:web:2031686a07c366ad3d78d5",
    measurementId: "G-T5K4SSB0X6"
  };


  class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        this.auth = app.auth();//enables authorisation for login
  }
    // *** Auth API ***
 
  doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) =>
    this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);//creating sign up fuction

  doSignInWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) =>
    this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);//creating sign in function

  doSignOut = () => this.auth.signOut();//creating sign out function

  doPasswordReset = email => this.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);//paswword reset function
 
  doPasswordUpdate = password =>
    this.auth.currentUser.updatePassword(password);//password update function

}
 
export default Firebase;
```

Comment: can you delete  `<hr />` to see whether it fixes issue?

Comment: have you added `<component/>` somewhere?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma yes. see index.js. MicSt, can you show the components/Firebase component?

Comment: @MoshFeu I have added the firebase components files at bottom of the post!

Comment: @ShubhamVerma I have looked everywhere for this and no I have not - I also capitalized the first letter of components I had made and was using e.g. WithFirebase and had no effect

Comment: @zhisme tried that thank you but had no effect

Comment: I have capitalised the C on component in src/components/Firebase/context.js but now I have a new error so I will update as I go on (if you see anything else that might be the issue please let me know)

Comment: Solved it in the end - so I capitalized the C as said before then I got even more errors and was led down a rabbit hole. To solve my issue in my src/components/app/index.js file I had to use a <HashRouter/> instead of <Router> for the navigation. If anyone could explain to me why it works with this instead I would be greatful.